# c# Process() does not run certain files when compiled in 32bit

Tags: c#

This code works in a 64 Bit build but not in a 32 bit build.
Is it possible to make it work in a 32 bit build?
What am I doing wrong here?

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\msconfig.exe";
p.Start();
```

Comment: Hint: There's no `msconfig.exe` under [`c:\Windows\SysWow64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Comment: Your application must request elevated privileges to run `msconfig.exe`. Are you doing that for the 64-bit version but not for the 32-bit version? Are you starting the process from a console app or a windows app? What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: @"C:\Windows\SysNative\msconfig.exe", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector

Comment: Greetings Matt, even with elevated permissions set it does not run.

Comment: Also It needs to run if the path is unqualified or not
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msconfig.exe";

Comment: I'm trying to run it from a 32bit app, no errors on either wpf or console. as a 64 bit app it runs.

Comment: How should one approach this issue to ensure either a 32bit or 64bit version is run and not knowing the exe name in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick, you can use 64-bit cmd.exe to pull a 64-bit application up.

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c start """" C:\Windows\System32\msconfig.exe";
p.Start();
```

The problem is a 32-bit application cannot directly access 64-bit cmd.exe, so there are 3 workarounds to achieve the purpose.

1. Use Sysnative directory

   ```
   p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative\cmd";
   ```
2. Turn off redirection with the windows API

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   private static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr oldValue);

   IntPtr intptr = IntPtr.Zero;
   if(Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref intptr))
   ```
3. Copy cmd.exe from C:\Windows\System32 to your working directory.

Comment: This code does NOT solve the issue. Tried and failed.

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Have a look, I have rewrote the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Shingo. Question. Let's say that this app is a HotKey app that a user can assign ANY program to run by a custom hotkey (32bit or 64 bit). Is this redirection able to manage running any type of file, resolving it's path?

Comment: I believe so, but I can't test for any program.  Added a new approach.

Comment: I was able to use this command line to run the 64 bit msconfig:
C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe| Q /S /C msconfig.exe

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the path below to run the msconfig from a 32 bit process:

```
C:\Windows\**sysnative**\cmd.exe|/Q /S /C msconfig.exe
```

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\sysnative\msconfig.exe";
p.Start();
```